# When lambda function and normal instance function gets memory in java?

Tags: java, memory, lambda, allocation

Below is the piece of code Where I implement lambda to perform various task.

```
package lambda;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        System.out.println(t.operate(1, 2, (a, b) -> a * b));
    }

    private int operate(int a, int b, Calculation method) {
        return method.operation(a, b);
    }

    interface Calculation {
        int operation(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

Now, the question is when and where my **operate** method gets memory?
and when I cal **t.operate** method using t.operate, when the lambda inside the parameter i.e (a,b)->a+b gets memory.
Also what are on-demand functions in java?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong.
According to me, lambda function get the memory in method area as like other references gets i.e static area.
But when we create an anonymous inner class.Java at the backend creates the object and that's why it gets the memory in heap area.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner classes get heap memory only allocated for instance variables. A direct comparison of heap usage between anonymous inner classes and lambda expressions makes only sense if only anonymous inner classes with a single overridden method and without instance variables are taken into account here. Then anonymous inner classes as well as lambda expressions would not need or get any memory on the heap. Only when a function call of the overridden method takes place memory for parameters and local variables of that method would be allocated on the stack. And then there would be no difference in the moment when memory is allocated and also almost no difference in the amount of RAM allocated (no reference to this and an instance of the outer class in the case of lambda expression).

Regarding on-demand functions: Not sure but maybe a *function builder* (a specific functional programming design pattern) is meant. This is a function that returns one of several possible functions or a parameterised function depending on input parameters. In Java this would be a method that returns an object of a certain interface e.g. a lambda expression.